# When activity crashes, the process stays alive and I cannot kill it

Tags: android, multithreading, crash, kill-process

I am developing an app with quite a few threads, it often crashes so far, whenever I load the new version from eclipse, it seems to create a new process.

I cannot seem to find a way to kill the old processes, they do not apear in the running apps.

I can see that I have multiple processes related to my app in the process list ("ps" command).

Is there a way to make sure the app process actually dies on crash?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` it can kill your process

Answer (score -1):

You can kill your app's process by:

```
System.exit(1);
```

It order to know when your app crashes (exception that's not being caught) you'll need to define:

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler());
```

In your main Thread.

CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler is:

```
public class CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    private UncaughtExceptionHandler    defaultUEH;

    public CustomUncaughtExceptionHandler()
    {
        this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
    }

    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
    {       
        // Put system.exit here
        if (defaultUEH != null)
        {
            defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
        }
        else
        {
            this.defaultUEH = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
            defaultUEH.uncaughtException(t, e);
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: This does not work, the app dies, when replacing it from Eclipse, but the processes stay, even if I actually uninstall it. Perhaps the exception is in another thread, do you think I should put that handler in the other threads too?